# How Can Angular Dart app be exported as library and be used in Angular Typescript project?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-dart

There is a AngularDart app with some components which i want to use in an Angular Typescript app, how can this be possible?

How Can Angular Dart app be exported as library and be used in Angular Typescript project? Or is there a way to wrap the Angular Dart in Angular Typescript and have communication between both?